Spring Boot Application on Tomcat 11 Returns 404 on Valid Endpoint
I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot Application on Tomcat11, but I am getting a 404 error when sending requests to valid endpoint.
I am using Java 21, Spring Boot 3.3.0 on Tomcat 11 with port 8082.
My application.properties file:
`cors.allowed-origins=http://localhost:3000
cors.allowed-headers=*
cors.allow-credentials=true
cors.allowed-methods=GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS

spring.application.name=ivr-test-automation-backend
server.port=8082
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://POSTGREIP:5432/ivr_test
spring.datasource.username=test_app
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.hikari.schema=ivr_test_automation
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.sql.init.mode=always

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

logging.level.org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.hibernate=WARN
logging.file.name=logs/ivr-test-automation-backend.log

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

# JWT
remote.auth.url=http://LDAPIP:992/api/v1/authenticate/login
remote.auth.secret=IVRLdap-Password
#jwt.secret=ivrTestAutomationSecret
jwt.expiration=36000000
jwt.secret = ${jwt.secret}

spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=true`

My AuthController
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthController {
.
.
.
 @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<JwtAuthenticationResponse>> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody LoginRequest authRequest) throws Exception {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.ldapName(), authRequest.password())
        );

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authRequest.ldapName());
        final String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        JwtAuthenticationResponse jwtAuthenticationResponse = getJwtAuthenticationResponse(authRequest.ldapName(), jwt);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(RestResponse.of(jwtAuthenticationResponse, AuthMessage.SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN));
    }
.
.
.

}

I am making the endpoint public with the following code block.
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, JwtTokenRefreshFilter jwtTokenRefreshFilter) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/role/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/user/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/permission/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/blacklist/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/scenario-configuration/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/scenario-configuration-history/**").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenRefreshFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                            response.getWriter().write(AuthMessage.SUCCESSFUL_LOGOUT.getMessage());
                        }));
        return http.build();
    }

On tomcat in server.xml file I added the Connector port for 8082
<Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="8443" />


When i run netstat -aon, the port is listening:
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::8082                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)

These are my settings. When I send a request on http://SERVERIP:8082/api/v1/auth/login via postman, I get the following error.

The application seems to be running successfully in the logs on catalina.out.
Example log that show deployment is success:

05-Sep-2024 19:43:57.201 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ivr-test-automation-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [11,316] ms

What could be causing this 404 error for a valid endpoint, and how can I fix it? If there is any config setting you want me to show, I can show it.
Any help would be appreciated!
I tried to add  address="0.0.0.0" to the server.xml file.
<Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               address="0.0.0.0" />

Then it took this form. The resuld did not change.
And when i tried sudo firewall-cmd --list-all, shows me.
[root@S200OUT03 logs]# sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
FirewallD is not running


what is the name of the war file (and the name of unpacked folder inside of tomcat webapps)? cause that context-path is usually gets prepended to any endpoint - so if ur war name is foo then your enpoint becomes /foo/api/v1/auth/login

Thank you for your help @JAsgarov, When I added the war file name, the problem was solved. So what should I do to use the war name without adding it?

you can change conf/server.xml to point directly to your webapp and then you won't need to keep prepending the context-path if that is what you asking... see here

I add this lines ìn the Host element.
<Context path="" docBase="ivr-test-automation-backend"/>
but the app runs twice
@JAsgarov

Please check your catalina.out file to confirm that Spring's logo text appears. like this: (you need copy this to your text editor to view it)  .   ____          _            __ _ _  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _ | \ \ \ 
\/  )| |)| | | | | || (| |  ) ) ) )
'  || .__|| ||| |_, | / / / /
=========||==============|/=///_/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)`
